# 301 redirect https non www to www htaccess in Chrome not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like redirect http://nyarfadent.hu to https://www.nyarfadent.hu
the result in Chrome:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /https://nyarfadent.hu/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
#rewrite http://nyarfadent.hu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nyarfadent\.hu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nyarfadent\.hu$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^www\.nyarfadent\.hu$ "https\:\/\/www\.nyarfadent\.hu\/" [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried width another chrome browser and it worked, the problem is solved

Comment: Your URL works fine for me. Try clearing your browser cache or use  a different browser for testing.

Comment: If this is solved, please add a self-answer below, rather than modifying the title. Stack Overflow has a acceptance/solution device on all answer posts.

Comment: I tried width another chrome browser and it worked, the problem is solved